No puedo acceder al csrftoken que envia Django en las cookies al frontend(React)
tengo un problema que nose si es mi backend(Django) o mi frontend(React), estoy utilizando un csrftoken como medida de seguridad, el backend y el frontend estan en dominios diferentes, Django en pythonanywhere y React en netlifly. Al entrar a mi frontend hace una peticion GET a django para que por medio las cookies django envie el csrftoken y despues acceder a el para enviarlo en la cabecera de alguna peticion POST, el problema es que no puedo acceder a el token aunque el httpOnly esta en false
REACT:
function getTokenCSRF(name){
   let cookieValue = null;

   if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
       const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');

       for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
           const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
  
           if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
               cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   return cookieValue;
}

DJANGO:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'content-type',
    'X-CSRFToken',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'Url de mi frontend',
]

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["Url de mi frontend"]
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "Url de mi frontend"

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

Tambien para añadir ya configure el navegador para que acepte cookies de terceros, en la cabecera de mi peticion GET y POST tiene el crendentials: 'include', el problema es que no puedo acceder al token con el codigo anterior de javascript; despues copie el token manualmente de las cookies del navegador y lo pegue como valor en la cabecera de X-CSFRToken en mi solicitud POST y salio todo perfecto.
